# Is there an equivalent of $(document).ready to initialise after re-loading part of a page?

Tags: jquery

I have the following pretty standard process:

1. I initialise my page in `$(document).ready`. This includes binding events to elements in a table.
2. The content of the table is then refreshed dynamically through an ajax call

I now need to rebind events to the table content. Is there a standard way of doing this? i.e. is there an equivalent of `$(document).ready` that fires after a **partial** page DOM update?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have a look at event delegation using [live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live). From the docs:

> When you bind a "live" event it will
>   bind to all current and future
>   elements on the page (using event
>   delegation). For example if you bound
>   a live click to all "li" elements on
>   the page then added another li at a
>   later time - that click event would
>   continue to work for the new element
>   (this is not the case with bind which
>   must be re-bound on all new elements).

An example:

```
$('#myTable td').live("click", function() {
    alert('hello!');
});
```

That will preserve the event(s) bound to the cells on the table even after it has been replaced. The [live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) manual says:

> Binds a handler to an event (like
>   click) for all current - and future -
>   matched element.

Alternatively, you can wrap your bindings into a function, and have that execute as a callback to the method that updates your table data, for instance:

```
function bindStuffToTable()
{
    $('#myTable td').click(function() {
       alert('Hello!');
    });
}

$('#myTable').load('/some/link', bindStuffToTable);
```

Or if the entire table gets replaced dynamically, which is more likely:

```
$('#someButton').click(function() {
    //replaces the contents of someDiv with the table generated by foo.php
    $('#someDiv').load('foo.php', bindStuffToTable);
});
```

Comment: Just to note that if you don't see any of the live stuff working, make sure your using the latest version of jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I looked at live events and also at the live plugin (which gives additional functionality). In the end I went with having a function that handled the rebinding - felt a bit less "smoke and mirrors". Thanks again.

Comment: [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has been removed as of jQuery 1.9; this answer should be updated to reference [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

I use $(document).ready() again if I receive a partial update...

**This is the AJAX response**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert($('div.partialresponse').html());
        //Alerts 'content'
    });
</script>
<div class="partialresponse">
   content
</div>
```

Comment: How does this work? Does the new "ready" function replace the one that was created on the intial page load?

Comment: I guess... The old one has executed already so it isn't needed anymore right? :)

Comment: ... but if the original $(document).ready() function created and initialised other functions - what happens to them? A quick test in IE6 seems to show they still remain, but it does feel a bit indeterminate.

Comment: You store those functions -outside- the document ready function right? E.g. inside a DOM element. Functions are passed by value, not reference. So if you -delete- the original ready() function the function definitions inside which you passed on before will not be deleted with it...

Comment: @Nick: Then those functions would continue to exist in the enclosure of the lamba passed to that 'first' `$(document).ready()` call.  Any processing in that first `$(document).ready()` is already done - leaving only variable and function definitions (which, as I say, will persist in the enclosure).

Comment: `.ready()` is a method, not a property -- you can execute it several times and any code you pass to it will be run as soon as possible, in the order it was added.